# Defining lists in prolog scripts

Tags: list, variables, prolog

I am new to prolog programming and have been told in a tutorial to define a list of structures (in a script) so that I can query it as a database. However I find it impossible to define this list as a variable in a script. When I define a list such as

```
X=[a,b,c].
```

I just receive an error saying

```
No permission to modify static_procedure `(=)/2'
```

Does prolog not support defining variables such as this? I am using SWI-Prolog under linux.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In Prolog we speak of *logical* variables, to mean *identity* between *literals*.

That is, a program it's a set of rules that collectively state what's true about our literals, and that literals are *uninterpreted*. We write rules using *variables* to describe *relations* about individuals, and while trying to prove if our query can become true, Prolog *binds* variables as rules dictate.

A *list* it's just syntax sugar for a binary relation between a term (the *head*) and (note the recursion here) a *list*. Usually, when we speak of a *database*, we use facts (rules without a body, always true) that binds atomic literals.

So that tutorial probably expresses the task in different words than you report, or it's somewhat misleading. You could anyway store lists in your database as such:

```
mylist([a,b,c]).
```

and write your program like:

```
myprog(X) :- mylist(L), member(X, L).
```

Then you can query your program like:

```
?- myprog(X).
```

and Prolog, trying to prove myprog/1, attempt to prove mylist/1 *and* member/2...
To prove mylist(L) the *variable* L get bound to [a,b,c].

HTH

Answer (score 8):

When you write

```
X = [a, b, c].
```

It's read as

```
=(X, [a, b, c]).
```

which is read as a definition of a fact concerning the `=/2` predicate. A fact where any free variable would be equal to `[a, b, c]`. That is, you redefine `=/2`. That's obviously not what you intend!

You have to remember in Prolog that variables are scoped only locally, inside a predicate. What would work is:

```
main :-
    X = [a, b, c],
    % do stuff with X.
```

Answer (score 2):

I use swipl under linux, to define a list in prolog.

```
mylist([element1,element2,elementn]).
```

Then you can query your program:

```
?- mylist(A).
```

Answer (score 1):

no, you cannot do it like this. what are you basically writing is:

```
=(X,[a,b,x]).
```

and as the error says you cannot redefine =/2

what you could do is:

```
x([a,b,c]).
```

and when you want to use X:

```
...
x(X),
foo(X)
...
```

Answer (score 1):

**If Y = [a,b,c], after the function makeList(Y,F) function call, F = [a,b,c]**

```
makeList(Y,F) :-
append(Y,[],X),
F = X.
```

e.g)

```
?- makeList([a,b,c],X).
X = [a,b,c].
```